# Jasper report export to xls is blank always even for simple report

Tags: jasper-reports, xls

I'm unable to export my jasper report in Excel format but the same works fine for pdf.  Below is my code snippet.. Kindly let me know where I'm going wrong

```
out = response.getOutputStream();

jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(filePath + fileName);

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, jasperParam, connection);

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);



exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

I'm using the below jars,

jasperreports-6.1.0.jar
 poi-3.9-20121203.jar

commons-digester-1.7.jar
 jfreechart-1.0.14.jar
 joda-time-2.4.jar

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Updating to poi-3.10.1.jar solved my issue..